# MySQL to PostgreSQL migration: mysql connector

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql

I am trying to migrate from MySQL to PostgreSQL and I have a Java-related problem that I am not able to fix. Full disclosure: I know little or nothing about Java, but the migration uses a Java-based script, so for me it becomes a configuration problem.

**Short version of the problem:**

The migration tool throws this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

`mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar` is already in the "JAVA_HOME\jre\lib\ext" directory, and I don't know how to solve this depencency problem.

---

**Long version of the problem:**

I was trying to migrate from MySQL to PostgreSQL. I checked the official postgresql documentation and I chose the free tool from entreprisedb (that can be downloaded [here](http://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads)) to start the migration.

From the installation readme, they tell you that the mysql connector is not installed by default, but they also tell you the steps to solve this problem:

> To enable MySQL connectivity, download MySQL's freely available JDBC driver from:
>   http://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/third-party-jdbc-drivers
>
> Place the `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar` file in the "JAVA_HOME\jre\lib\ext" directory (in my case: "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\ext\mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar").

After configuring the tool properly and executing the .bat, this is the error I get:

```
Connecting with source MySQL database server...
MTK-11009: Error Connecting Database "MySQL Server"
DB-null: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Stack Trace:
com.edb.MTKException: MTK-11009: Error Connecting Database "MySQL Server"
    at com.edb.dbhandler.mysql.MySQLConnection.<init>(MySQLConnection.java:48)
    at com.edb.common.MTKFactory.createMTKConnection(MTKFactory.java:250)
    at com.edb.MigrationToolkit.createNewSourceConnection(MigrationToolkit.java:5982)
    at com.edb.MigrationToolkit.initToolkit(MigrationToolkit.java:3346)
    at com.edb.MigrationToolkit.main(MigrationToolkit.java:1700)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at com.edb.Utility.processException(Utility.java:327)
    at com.edb.dbhandler.mysql.MySQLConnection.<init>(MySQLConnection.java:47)
    ... 4 more
```

...which, to my understanding, probably means that `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar` is not found.

All the links I've found online regarding the error are specific for Eclipse or other IDEs, so I have not yet been able to solve this dependency problem.

Comment: the connector must be placed in your project not in JRE

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**

With the help of a friend that masters Java, this is the solution he achieved:

To start looking for the problem, we opened the `runMTK.bat`. The execution line reads:

```
cscript //nologo "..\etc\sysconfig\runJavaApplication.vbs" "..\etc\sysconfig\edbmtk-49.config" "-Dprop=..\etc\toolkit.properties -classpath -jar edb-migrationtoolkit.jar %*"
```

So then we opened this `runJavaApplication.vbs`, and in order to know the `JAVA_EXECUTABLE_PATH` that the program was using, we add this line to the script:

```
Wscript.Echo "JAVA_EXECUTABLE_PATH = " & JAVA_EXECUTABLE_PATH
```

With that info, we discover that the script is using the Java folder under `C:\Program Files (x86)`, instead of the one under `C:\Program Files` (where I dropped the mysql jar). So we copy the `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar` in the `\ext` folder of the x86, and now the script works.

Word of advice: the script is throwing errors in half of the exported tables, so all the hassle may not be worth it. BUT if anyone is interested in making this migration script work from A to Z (which has been quite a challenge), here are the details:

---

**HOW TO**

Free tool (from entreprisedb):
http://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads

Extract the files from the zip and fun the installer (`ppasmeta-9.5.0.5-windows-x64.exe`) as administrator.

To enable MySQL connectivity, download MySQL's freely available JDBC driver from:
http://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/third-party-jdbc-drivers

Place the `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar` file in the "JAVA_HOME\jre\lib\ext" directory (in my case: "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\ext\mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar").

The Migration Toolkit documentation can be found:

- here (online doc): https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/en/9.4/migrate/toc.html
- or here (pdf doc): http://get.enterprisedb.com/docs/Postgres_Plus_Migration_Guide_v9.5.pdf

First: modify `C:\Program Files\PostgresPlus\edbmtk\etc\toolkit.properties` ([Info here](https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/en/9.4/migrate/Postgres_Plus_Migration_Guide.1.14.html#)):

```
SRC_DB_URL=jdbc:mysql://SOURCE-HOST-NAME/SOURCE-DB-NAME
SRC_DB_USER=********
SRC_DB_PASSWORD=********

TARGET_DB_URL=jdbc:edb://localhost:5444/DESTINATION-DB-NAME
TARGET_DB_USER=enterprisedb
TARGET_DB_PASSWORD=********
```

Then: execute `C:\Program Files\PostgresPlus\edbmtk\bin\runMTK.bat` ([Info here](https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/en/9.4/migrate/Postgres_Plus_Migration_Guide.1.21.html)).

```
runMTK.bat -sourcedbtype mysql -targetdbtype enterprisedb -allTables YOUR_DB_SCHEMA

// ...or with a limited subset of tables:

runMTK.bat -sourcedbtype mysql -targetdbtype enterprisedb -tables TABLE1,TABLE2,TABLE3 YOUR_DB_SCHEMA
```

In order to get this subset of tables from MySQL:

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(TABLE_NAME)
FROM
    information_schema.tables
WHERE
    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_db_name'
```

Comment: I am tryig to work with your solution but keep on getting DB-null: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
2017-06-18 17:07:00 Stack Trace:
com.edb.MTKException: MTK-11009: Error Connecting Database "MySQL Server"
 at com.edb.dbhandler.mysql.MySQLConnection.<init>(MySQLConnection.java:48)
 at com.edb.common.MTKFactory.createMTKConnection(MTKFactory.java:263)
 at com.edb.MigrationToolkit.createNewSourceConnection(MigrationToolkit.java:6357)

Comment: where did u add this line **Wscript.Echo "JAVA_EXECUTABLE_PATH = " & JAVA_EXECUTABLE_PATH** ?